# How to optimize the Speed and memory in Ruta Process?

Tags: performance, memory, uima, ruta

I need to optimize the speed and memory of my Ruta Process.I've reviewed the following links [Uima Ruta Out of Memory issue in spark context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351051/uima-ruta-out-of-memory-issue-in-spark-context) and  [CPU usage too high while running Ruta Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218061/cpu-usage-too-high-while-running-ruta-script), I've reduced few seconds.Still I need to Optimize the Process. Why i'm asking this because a file which is running in -Xms512M -Xmx8192M Memory Configuration is not running in -Xms512M -Xmx1536M Memory Configuration.Showing **Java Heap Space or GC Overhead Limit error**.How can I reduce the memory Usage?

Comment: I'm using 2.5.0.How disjunctive rule looks in ruta

Comment: It depedns on where the memory is used up. Did you try to profile it, e.g., with jvisualvm?

Comment: IF you want ot optimize, you should remove all conjunctive and disjunctive rules.

Comment: Are you asking me to remove conjunctive and disjunctive rules or instead of & and | need to use AND and OR .

Comment: Yes, or to use two rules instead or other refactorings.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question. It's like asking how to optimize a java program. It depends on the actual program (or rules in this case). I would first use the Ruta profiling and then a java profiler to identify the bottelnecks, and then fix or avoid them.